# Nested Component Without Using Directives

Tags: angular

According to John Papa's tutorial, he uses the `directives` attribute inside of `@component` when depending on another component. Apparently, `directives` has been removed in RC6 and the alternative is to use it inside of `@ngModule` in `declarations`.

Is there another alternative that could allow us to nest components without needed to include all of them inside of `@ngModule`?

https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/4a740f2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `@NgModule()` is the way to go since RC6 and there are no alternatives.

There was quite some discussion but I haven't seen any serious arguments why this would be needed.

Comment: well i haven't heard of it. it might be cleaner, but this really closes some possibilities of writing the code. having the hierarchy of cascading imports has it's benefits. i guess it's not too bad though.

Comment: What possibilities are closed?

Comment: being able to just import one component in @ngModule instead of including all of that one component and it's subcomponents.

Comment: You just need to think a bit more how you distribute your components and directives to modules. They designed it that way to make it work with lazy loading in combination with the router.